# multi level vertical list -> horizontal list

Tags: html-lists, stylesheet

```
       <ul>
         <li>main list
          <ul>
           <li>sub list A
            <ul>
             <li>sub list A-1</li>
             <li>sub list A-2</li>
             <li>sub list A-3</li>
             <li>sub list A-4</li>
             <li>sub list A-5</li>
            </ul>
           </li>
           <li>sub list B
            <ul>
             <li>sub list B-1</li>
             <li>sub list B-2</li>
             <li>sub list B-3</li>
            </ul>
           </li>
           <li>sub list C
            <ul>
             <li>sub list C-1</li>
             <li>sub list C-2</li>
             <li>sub list C-3</li>
            </ul>
           </li>
          </ul>
         </li>
        </ul>
```

I am a Korean. 
    So I can not speak English well. 
    Please excuse, even if I do not understand my words.

I have a list of one. 
    This list has a vertical structure. 
    But I want to change it horizontally. 
    In order to be listed in a horizontal list, what should I do? 
    I can use a style sheet only. 
    ul li {} 
    ul li ul li {} 
    ul li ul li ul li {} 
    Please design like the example below.

main list - sub list A - sub list A-1, sub list A-2, sub list A-3 ..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for this if I understand you:

http://jsfiddle.net/Robuuust/Dxv6C/1/

css: `ul {display:inline-block}`

Comment: Thank you very much. But, this structure is different. 
I want to do is going to transform the multi-level structure.

Comment: Does not solve the problem.
but, Thank you very much for your help.